# Software for Automated Batch Merge of PDF files

Tags: pdf

Is there any free software that can batch merge batched pdf files into separate files.

For instance first batch consists of 1111.3425.pdf, 1111.76501.pdf, so on. Second batch is 22222.1432.pdf, 22222.4398, so on. And so on and so forth for other batches.

I need it to be free and automated such that does not need to write scripts or invoking command line terminal.

Comment: Please specify a OS, or indicate you don't care

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this [Dysprosium](http://www.messiahpsychoanalyst.org/Documents/Downloads.html#part12) free software that can be used in this way

◦ Files should be batch separated by one dot as "xxxxx.abcdef.pdf"

◦ Each batch common tag sequence, that is, xxxx can be any length.

◦ Each file identifier in the batch, that is, abcdef can be of any length.

◦ Each merged file comes as xxxx_Batch.pdf with its common tag in the same directory.

◦ All files should be in the same directory, mixed with other file types or just PDF.

◦ Files in the list receive automatic dictionary sort. Any other sort is possible only manually in the GUI, using "Move Up" and "Move Down" buttons.

◦ Any PDF file that is not in form of xxxx.abcdef.pdf or the result of the previous operations should be removed manually using remove button or before the beginning from the batching directory.

Number of file and length of each could be thousands on condition of having enough hardware power to handle it.

It comes as a portable JAR file that is cross platform on all machines that run Java, Windows, Unix type including Linux, or MAC.

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu I use [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) for this purpose. It has a GUI, but
also a command line interface (shown below). In the GUI simply
add the pdf files you want to include and press create pdf. Batch
processing would have to be done with including whole folders or the
like, but it is simpler with the command line interface.

**command line interface**

Simply run the following command:

```
pdftk file1.pdf file2.pdf file3.pdf cat output newfile.pdf
```

As for running it in a big batch, you can do

```
pdftk folder/*.pdf cat output newfile.pdf
```

to merge all files in one folder.

Comment: Worth mentioning here that pdftk is available for multiple platforms and is free, (base gui and command line), or ridiculously cheap for the pro version.

Comment: Looking for something like this, but macOS GUI and free. App Store has something for $1.99.

Answer (score 0):

PdfCpu works great:

```
pdfcpu merge c.pdf a.pdf b.pdf
```

https://pdfcpu.io/core/merge